# How to open MS Edge with specific profile with selenium webDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am running automation on the edge browser. Edge browser supports profile and whenever i launch the edge from webdriver, it create new profile. Is there any way I can set the option to launch edge with given user profile ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use Java language as an example. You could use `user-data-dir` and `profile-directory` to use specific profile to launch Edge with Selenium. The sample code is like below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "your\\path\\to\\edge\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();

// Here you set the path of the profile ending with User Data not the profile folder
edgeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");

// Here you specify the actual profile folder
edgeOptions.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 2");

edgeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

**Note:** Change the paths in the code to your owns.

If you don't know the path of the specific profile, you could check `edge://version/` like below:

[image]