# Is there a way that you can use the browser profiles on your desktop as the Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using the the msedge driver and chromedriver as the webdriver for Selenium in Python. I was wondering if there was a way that I can use the various chrome and edge profiles I have on my desktop as the webdriver so that when run my program, it opens my desired edge profile and runs the code there. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3) && [How to open MS Edge with specific profile with selenium webDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242103/how-to-open-ms-edge-with-specific-profile-with-selenium-webdriver)